# Need a Stored Procedure, select distinct, for each select count(*), and format output as a table

Tags: t-sql

Ok I do not know enough about t-sql yet to do what I need to do ~ or to even know if it's possible.

I need a stored procedure in which I can specify a username and get back a count of how many items of each type exist in a table for that user.

For example, I specify `@username = 'joshf'`

I need to then have the stored procedure do:

`SELECT DISTINCT [Type] FROM [dbo].[request]`

And then for each type listed I need it to:

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS @type FROM [dbo].[request] WHERE [Type] = @PipelineItem AND [AssignedTo] = @username`

I need the output to be in a table formatted like:

| Type | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Type1 | 1 |
| Type2 | 0 |
| Type3 | 4 |
| Type4 | 1 |

I was trying to do something with creating a composite @SQLQuery and executing it with Execute sp_Executesql but I am running out of ideas for how to get the results as a table like I need.

Comment: Please provide some sample data along with the expected results

Comment: What would you like `COUNT(*) AS @type` to do?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a `GROUP BY` query

The following query will gives the count for all [Type] that is [AssignedTo] `@username`.

```
SELECT [Type],
       COUNT (*)
FROM   [dbo].[request]
WHERE  [AssignedTo] = @username 
GROUP BY [Type]
```

But as you wanted to include [Type] that is also not [AssignedTo] to `@username`, like `Type2`, you can't put the condition in the `WHERE` clause. You will need a conditional `CASE` expression to perform the `count`

```
SELECT [Type],
       SUM (CASE WHEN [AssignedTo] = @username THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Count]
FROM   [dbo].[request]
GROUP BY [Type]
```

Comment: Jesus - I was overthinking this so hard.  Thank you a ton.

It doesn't specifically address the select distinct from a different table to get types that are not used in the primary table ~ but in retrospect that is probably overkill for my purposes anyway.